# Haskell recursion odd

Tags: list, haskell

I have to define my own predicate function that recursively searches a list of numbers and returns `True` if it finds an odd number, `False` otherwise.

I have set `X = [1..100]` for test data that I need to show. However, I am a bit unsure about how to get recursion to search the list. I'm not looking for the definitive answer but an explanation on how recursion would go around searching in a list.

Comment: Are you wanting to turn something like `[1,2,3,4]` into `[True,False,True,False]`?

Comment: What I want is if any of the numbers in the list are odd the the response would be true, If there are no odd numbers then it would return False, and if the list is empty it should be False

Comment: So `f [] == False`, `f [1, 2] == True`, `f [2, 4] == False`?

Comment: So you want `any odd`?

Comment: @Harry If you're happy with the answer you got, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the function `any odd`:

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool

Odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool

any odd :: Integral a => [a] -> Bool

anyOdd :: Integral a => [a] -> Bool
anyOdd = any odd
```

If you want to define the `anyOdd` function yourself then you would have to use recursion:

```
anyOdd :: Integral a => [a] -> Bool
anyOdd []       = undefined
anyOdd (x:xs)
    | odd x     = undefined
    | otherwise = undefined
```

You will need to replace `undefined` with your actual logic.

Comment: how do i show my code with the grey background? like you have done so

Comment: still can't do it, anyways I used the code you provided, and filled in the logic parts with 

anyoddp []      = False

and

anyOdd (x:xs) = True

this however doesn't return correctly.

I write out anyoddp (x:xs)  = -> odd then true

and it gives me the error that parase error on input ->

Comment: I updated my answer. Replace `undefined` with what you think is correct.

Comment: In the end I got what you had but instead i had a where odd was.

Thank you for the help

Comment: How come when I input decimal numbers into the test data it returns     
No instance for (Integral Double) arising from a use of ‘anyoddp’
    In the expression: anyoddp e
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = anyoddp e

Comment: The `odd` predicate can only be used on `Integral` numbers like -1, 0, 1, etc. It cannot be used on numbers with decimals. Hence you can't use it with `Double` which can have decimal numbers.

Comment: is there any way that this problem could be fixed?

I thought integral numbers included all 5 instances of the num class

int, integer, float, double and rational

Comment: @Harry There's no widespread notion of e.g. "odd rational", or of "odd real" (is `sqrt 2` odd?), so `odd` is not defined on such types.

Comment: There is another problem though >< if the first element isn't an odd number it still comes up as fales, for example c = [2,3,5,7,8] it still returns false, how would I correct this?

Comment: | odd x = False
| otherwise = True

Comment: It should be `| otherwise = anyOdd xs`.